# ¿Cómo podría tener dos servidores apache y balancear las conexiones entre ellos para evitar cortes en Windows?

Tags: php, apache

Tenemos un windows 2012 con apache 2.2 y php 5.3 que sufre muchos problemas incluso con pocos usuarios.

Al principio aparecía con mucha frecuencia el mensaje:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 18442) (tried to allocate 276 bytes) in ...

Lo solucionamos reduciendo `MaxRequestsPerChild` a 10. Al hacerlo se producen multitud de microcortes en la intranet de conexión rechazada que habitualmente duran un instante, pocas veces varios segundos pero en casos excepcionales dura varios minutos.

Aumentando `MaxRequestsPerChild` a 50 los cortes se producen con menos frecuencia pero cuando son los largos se nota mucho entre los usuarios y si aumentamos a un valor más alto se vuelven a producir los errores de memoria.

No podemos usar IIS para servir páginas php porque usamos y dependemos de muchos archivos `.htpasswd` y `.htaccess` complejos y no podemos usar Linux porque los usuarios dejan archivos en carpetas compartidas y podría haber problemas con las mayúsculas y minúsculas. Tampoco podemos montar un cluster con dos máquinas porque solo hay una licencia de Windows 2012.

¿Cómo podría tener dos servidores apache y balancear las conexiones entre ellos para evitar cortes usando el propio Apache o IIS por encima?

Comment: Estoy ahora ocupado con otra respuesta, gracias por avisar, en unos minutos trataré de redactar la tuya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El procese se divide en dos partes. La primera parte creará varios servidores sobre los que se balancearán las conexiones mediante un balanceador que se configurará en la segunda parte.

## Parte 1: Múltiples instancias de Apache

Primero deberemos crear dos o más servicios Apache que recibirán y atenderán las conexiones de los clientes en diferentes puertos (8000, 8001, etc).

Localiza tu archivo `httpd.conf` y cambia allí el parámetro `Port 80` por `Port 8000`.

Hazte una copia del archivo y llámalo (por ejemplo) `httpd_8001.conf`.En él cambia el parámetro a `Port 8001` igual que antes, pero cambia también los archivos de log de acceso y log de error de tus sitios web. Agrégale `_8001`, por ejemplo. Si no haces esto último es probable que el servicio no arranque por estar el archivo en uso por otro servicio Apache.

Crea un segundo servicio de Windows que use este nuevo archivo de configuración de la siguiente manera:

```
CD C:\(Ruta al binario de tu apache)
httpd.exe -k install -n "Apache 8001" -f "C:\(Ruta al nuevo archivo de configuración)\httpd_8001.conf"
```

Reinicia ambos servicios y comprueba que puedes acceder a ellos con `http://<servidor>:8000/` y `http://<servidor>:8001/`.

Si tienes la posibilidad de usar el [módulo rpaf](https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf) podrás mantener las IPs de origen de las conexiones de tus clientes, en caso contrario todas verán la IP del balanceador (localhost o la IP de tu servidor).

## Parte 2: Balanceador web (Squid)

Podrías hacer uso de cualquier software o hardware balanceador, incluso el propio Apache, pero para evitar el mal rendimiento que tiene Apache bajo Windows haremos uso de [Squid 2.7 para Windows](http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/Squid27.html) o [Squid 3.5 para Windows](http://squid.diladele.com/#services).

Para configurar un acelerador web sencillo debes seguir [esta guía](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy#Running_the_web_server_on_the_same_server).

Tras seguir los [pasos de instalación](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/Windows#Installing_Squid) deberás cambiar el archivo `squid.conf` con las siguientes modificaciones:

```
# Escuchamos en el puerto 80 en modo aceleración como frontal de los dos Apache
http_port 80 accel
# Configuramos los dos Apache que atenderán las conexiones:
cache_peer localhost parent 8000 0 no-query originserver round-robin login=PASS
cache_peer localhost parent 8001 0 no-query originserver round-robin login=PASS
```

Tras reiniciar el servicio de Squid deberás poder acceder al servidor, de nuevo, a través de `http://<servidor>/`.

Comment: He probado con el nuevo servicio y he tenido que hacer cambios y cambiar el puerto 443 al 444. Aún así al probarlo me aparecen algunas cosas raras en el HTML. Cuando se usa $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] para montar urls aparecen 8001 por http y 444 por https. Funciona porque ahora accedo a través de ese puerto, pero eso no haría que accediera al servidor directamente más adelante? todo esto funciona en Windows 7? voy a hacer las pruebas en mi equipo antes de hacerlo en el servidor.

Comment: Prueba a buscar la definición de virtualhosts y en donde ponga `ServerName <host>` pon `ServerName <host>:80` y `ServerName <host>:443`. Si no tienes ninguno dentro de las etiquetas `<VirtualHost>` entonces pon en su interior `ServerName :80` y `ServerName :443`. PHP obtiene, por defecto, el puerto de esa directiva en caso de estar definida. Prueba y me cuentas. PD: Sí, todo debe funcionar en W7 igual que en W2012.

Comment: Ha funcionado y sale todo bien, la semana que viene probaré squid en mi equipo. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Alguna novedad? ¿Pudiste probarlo ya?

Comment: No, lo siento. No es fácil hacer una modificación así de grande en un servicio tan crítico. Esta semana es posible que haga avances.

Comment: Lo resolví con ayuda en parte de tu respuesta con dos apaches como propusiste y un balanceador externo. Gracias.